# Select internal/external DVDD source for OV5640

Tags: image-sensor

How to select between internal or external source for the DVDD digital core in [OV5640](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/LightImaging/OV5640_datasheet.pdf). Do I simply provide voltage to the DVDD pins and if it is more than 1.5V it will automatically use internal LDO to get 1.5V, or when they are unconnected/grounded it starts generating its own 1.5V, or there is a proper way to do it?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I meant the DVDD pins to which 1.5V should be connected (see the schematic on p.21).

Answer (score 1):

If DOVDD of OV5650 is 1.8V, then DVDD is generated by internal regulator of OV5640

For more details refer to [OV5640 Auto Focus Camera Module Application Notes](http://www.arducam.com/downloads/modules/OV5640/OV5640_Software_app_note_parallel.pdf).